# removing quotes from nested json passed value

Tags: python, json, variables, replace, strip

I'm writing a MS Graph function to send mail.  I've tried many variations of how to collect the data from the function and pass it successfully to the JSON payload, but cannot strip the inevitable quotes.  The users pass the following for args to a function.  cc_user_emails can be a list of varying size.

```
to_user_email = 'hello.world@test.com'
cc_user_emails = ['hello.usa@scripps.com', 'hello.dc@scripps.com'] 
subject = 'hey'
message = 'it looks like i cant remove quotes from this'

cc_user_labels = [{"emailAddress":{"address": i}} for i in cc_user_emails]

email_msg =  {
"message": {
"subject": f"{subject}",
"body": {
  "contentType": "Text",
  "content": f"{message}"
},
"toRecipients": [
  {
    "emailAddress": {
      "address": f"{to_user_email}"
    }
  }
],
"ccRecipients": [
    ', '.join(map(str, cc_user_labels)).replace('"',"")
    ]
},
"saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

when i print that, I still get quotes around the ccRecipients' values:

```py
from json import dumps
print(dumps(email_msg, indent=2))
```

Which prints:

```
{
"message":{
  "subject":"hey",
  "body":{
     "contentType":"Text",
     "content":"it looks like i cant remove quotes from this"
  },
  "toRecipients":[
     {
        "emailAddress":{
           "address":"hello.world@test.com"
        }
     }
  ],
  "ccRecipients":[
     {
        "{'emailAddress': {'address': 'hello.usa@test.com'}}, {'emailAddress':         {'address': 'hello.dc@test.com'}}"
     }
  ]
},
"saveToSentItems":"true"
}
```

Notice the extra quotes around the ccRecipients email addresses?
How do I get it to look like proper JSON?  This variable sends every time:

```
{
          "message": {
            "subject": "hey",
            "body": {
              "contentType": "Text",
              "content": "it looks like i cant remove quotes from this"
            },
            "toRecipients": [
              {
                "emailAddress": {
                  "address": "hello.world@test.com"
                }
              }
            ],
            "ccRecipients": [
              {
                "emailAddress": {
                  "address": "hello.usa@test.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "emailAddress": {
                  "address": "hello.dc@test.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "saveToSentItems": "true"
        }
```

Comment: Quotes that are literal data cannot substitute for quotes that are syntax. Where you have the code `', '.join(map(str, cc_user_labels)).replace('"',"")` generating a string that looks like an object, you need code that generates an _actual object_, not a string at all.

Comment: I'd start with `"ccRecipients": cc_user_labels,`, and try to work towards what you need from there. Exactly what is it that makes any munging necessary at all?

Comment: hold on, im a bit confused. so whats the desired type of `ccRecipients` - as a `str` or `list` type? for graph call I assume something like `{emailAddress: {address: 'hello.usa@test.com'}}` is desired.

Comment: btw, what i'm meaning by list type is if you substitute how you're instantiing the dict type, so for ex like `"ccRecipients": cc_user_labels` then that is the output that i think you are desiring, unless i'm mistaken. or perhaps that was the previous output before the attempt at replacing the quotes, not entirely sure in this case tbh (perhaps adding additional clarification might help out here as well)

Comment: BTW, the output you gave us is _definitely not_ exactly what your program prints, because it isn't valid JSON at all; `{ "some string" }` is invalid, so `json.dumps()` can't ever generate it.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ymEJN3 -- what exactly is wrong with that?